# Finding new files in the current git tag compared to previous tag

Tags: git, version-control

For example I have the following files in tag: `v1.0.1`

```
a
b
c
```

and for tag: `v1.0.2` the files are as follows:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Now how do we get the list of new files present in the repo for the latest tag ?

The answer for the above example should be:

```
d
e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag identifies a commit.  A commit contains a snapshot—a set of files.

`git diff` compares sets-of-files, including two different snapshots.  Simply point `git diff` at two specific commits—two snapshots—and it will give you instructions for converting one to the other:

```
git diff v1.0.1 v1.0.2
```

The only problem is that `git diff` shows you the *complete instructions* by default, while you want to know *what files are affected*.  Fortunately `git diff` has knobs you can turn to make it reduce or change its output, such as `--name-status`:

```
$ git diff --name-status v1.0.1 v1.0.2
M       Makefile
M       debian/changelog
M       quote.c
M       server-info.c
```

The "status" letter at the front tells you what Git thinks happened to the file: `M` means "modified", "D" means "deleted", and so on.  The most interesting for your particular case is `A`, which means "added": the file is in the second commit, but not in the first.

Hence, you want to select the files from this list that have status `A` (in my example none do but in your example some will).  Fortunately `git diff` has a knob for this as well:

```
git diff --diff-filter=A <options> <arguments>
```

You could keep the `--name-status` so that it doesn't show the *contents* of the files, but this will still show the letter `A`; so you will want `--name-only` to print *just* the names:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A v1.0.1 v1.0.2
```

and you're done.